#  authentication page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried few examples in rails and it went wrong in some way. Finally i looked at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise_example.git , which works correctly but i find it difficult to understand how it works or the process of getting it done. So if someone can help me by explaining the steps involved in the same example if possible or the other, i can understand it. Thanks.

Comment: what specific problem did you encounter?

Comment: I am new to rails, so i just did those that were mentioned in readme file. But if i can know the steps to start off, i can try on my own.

Comment: If you are able to complete all the installation steps up to `Run the server` without problems, you already have everything you need to get started, the rest is pretty much up to individual customization.

Comment: I ran and it works, but that is not what i want. As i have said earlier, i have tried few examples and it was in those sites they gave the steps like "rails g controller home index" So i did that, and hence i saw the result of that. similarly how to do for this example

Answer (score 0):

You might want to watch the RailsCasts episode on Devise: http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise